# Couldn't figure out linked list failure

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

Im getting a breakpoint and failure (sometimes the IDE says it's stack overflow although I'm using the heap buffer) I coulnd't figure out why, I've tested the same file on previous versions of my code and it worked without any errors.

That's the error I get:

[image: Tat's the error I get]

the struct I use:

```
typedef struct { //pixel's coordinates
    int x;
    int y;
}co_t;

typedef struct pixel { //list of pixels
    co_t p;
    struct pixel* next;
}pix_t;
```

allocating memory

```
void pix_insert(pix_t** root, co_t coordinate) {
    pix_t* new_pix = malloc(sizeof(pix_t));
    if (new_pix == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    new_pix->next = NULL;
    new_pix->p.x = coordinate.x;
    new_pix->p.y = coordinate.y;

    if (*root == NULL) {
        *root = new_pix;
        return;
    }

    pix_t* curr = *root;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = new_pix;
}
```

deallocating

```
void deallocpix(pix_t* root) {
    pix_t* curr;
    while (root != NULL) {
        curr = root;
        root = root->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}
```

overall explanation on the code:

1. I'm loading a 24 bit BMP image, and mapping each pixel RGB value to 2D matrix, then converting the RGB values to 1 or 0 according to the color (1 = blue 0 = other color)
2. using image segmantation on the 1,0 matrix to count size of each group, I'm doing it by adding the '1' pixels to linked list as shown above,

that's the link to the github since I didn't won't to post all of the code (because it is all in the soure.c file)[My code's github](https://github.com/One2mellow/Amphibic_Probe)

in the Github folder, there are several BMP files that you can use to check the program with, all you need to do is to enter the file name in the top of the code under

```
#define BMP "(BMP file name).bmp"
```

the blue pixels are (155,190,245) RGB

the error occurs when entering 1 in the menu

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with function `deallocpix()` itself.  It may be that the issue is triggered by an altogether unrelated error, but more likely is that you are passing a wild pointer to this function, or that the list you are trying to deallocate is not properly terminated by a node having `next == NULL`.  If you want help identifying the specific source then we need to see a [mre].

Comment: @Nit Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.ai Dan

Comment: You have the one of the easiest to use and most powerful debuggers available with your Visual Studio. Use it.

Comment: I cloned your github repository and ran your code, but it's useless without any test input.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've updated the post with instructions to use the test input,
I've used the debugger and that's how I figured out that the fault happens after 2197 calls to the pix_insert functions